# iOS Core Data - Serious application error - attempt to insert nil - in less than 1%

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

iOS Core Data - Serious application error - attempt to insert nil

Hello,

My app runs actualy stable, but in seldom cases it crashes with this error message...

> 2019-04-02 20:48:52.437172+0200 myAppName[4422:1595677] [error] error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
>   CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
>   2019-04-02 20:48:52.438246+0200 myAppName[4422:1595677] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'

...when it tries to save the current context (this part in my code is still in objc):

```
- (void)saveChanges
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSError *err = nil;
        BOOL succesful = [self->context save:&err];
        if (!succesful)
        {
            NSLog(@"ERROR MESSAGE DURING SAVING CONTEXT: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
        }
    });
}
```

'seldom' means:
Most Customers do never experience the issue, for few customers it happens several times per day.
I was able to produce it 2 times during the last two days although I tried several ways to force this error (see below).

This is the setup:

- The respective data is in one Entity (table)
- A NSFetchedResultsController shows the data in an UITableView
- User can hit a button to add a new record.
- New record has only some basic data and initiates two API calls to two webservers
- Each webserver response does update the record
- After both are done (or were cancelled due to timeout), I call the saveChanges function from above only once.
- All functions use the same context created by NSPersistentContainer as follow (this part is already in swift)

```
@objc lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "myAppName")
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: SomeHelper.urlForFileInDocFolder("storev7.data"))
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })

        return container
 }()
```

If I could reproduce the error somehow, I could find an appropriate solution, but as it almost never happens, I'm stuck.

**Do you have an idea how I could reproduce the error from above? Or do you have a clue what could cause the error in my case?**

What I tried already to reproduce the error:

- Create hundereds of record
- Create hundereds of record in a few seconds
- Create hundereds of record during switching internet connection on / off / on / off /...
- Create hundereds of record during mixed from background and main thread (I removed the dispatch from saveChanges for that)
- Create hundereds of record with different delays on the API (added random sleep function on the webserver)
- Long time execution, the app run for 24 hours on a real device and created record each 2 minutes
- Mixes of all of them

Comment: What concurrencyType is this context? Is the caller of `-save` on the main queue or another queue? Does that queue modify context in any way?

Comment: @RobNapier I expect it to be `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`, but I do not define it. I just use `NSPersistentContainer` as shown above to create the context by using `persistentContainer.viewContext`. I dispatch also all `-save` requests to main thread. And I do not change the context after it's created initially.

Comment: `viewContext` is good; that matches. Do you make changes to any of the records on any queue other than the main queue (not just save; any changes. NSManagedObjects are not thread safe, not even for reading.)

Comment: @RobNapier only to the the current one, I create a new object with `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyEntityName" inManagedObjectContext:context];`, afterwards it get changed from main and backgorund threads (from web api calls), and at the end I call once `context save` in main thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NSManagedObjects are restricted to a single queue. They are not thread-safe for reading or writing. Reading an NSManagedObject can cause a fault, which is a write operation. That means that NSManagedObjects retrieved from a main queue context (like `viewContext`) cannot be passed to other queues.

The details of all of this are discussed in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH24-SW1):

> NSManagedObject instances are not intended to be passed between queues. Doing so can result in corruption of the data and termination of the application. When it is necessary to hand off a managed object reference from one queue to another, it must be done through NSManagedObjectID instances.

The general approach with NSPersistentContainer is to use something like `viewContext` exclusively on the main queue, and to use `performBackgroundTask` to handle background operations, or you can use `newBackgroundContext` to generate a background context, and use `perform` or `performAndWait` on it to manipulate objects that are fetched from that context.

Moving an object between contexts is done by fetching the same `objectID` in the other context (keeping in mind that this will return a fresh instance from the store).

[You can track down mistakes by adding `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1` to your scheme.](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/) When you do this, errors will immediately trap on the delightfully named `__Multithreading_Violation_AllThatIsLeftToUsIsHonor__`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Makes totally sense to me! Just one additional question: If I follow this approach, and create two dedicated private context to manipulate the objects with the response of the web server API call, can I then call `-save` 3 times? Once from main thread after initial creation and two times in `performBackgroundTask` on private context after loading the object with `existingObjectWithID:error` in advance?

Comment: In other words, it is no problem if two or more `-save` happen at the same time as long as each has its own context?

Comment: If there's no conflict, then there's no problem. But if there's a conflict, it'll throw an error. As long as every context manages its own objects on its own queue, it's designed to manage concurrency. Think of it like a database COMMIT.

Comment: Conflict means writing/reading the same attribute (column) on one row from different queues, right? Reading/writing different attributes on the same row from different queues is ok, right?

Comment: No, any modification will cause a conflict by default. See `mergePolicy` for how to set an override, but if you're doing a lot of work on the same objects like this, you should likely dispatch all the modification work to a single background context to serialize the changes. I don't believe there is any merge policy that looks like "throw error on per-property conflicts." You can auto-merge per-property conflicts, but errors are produced for total-object version mismatches. (That said, you can always just check the conflict dictionary and decide what to do to merge the data yourself.)

Comment: "Throws a merge conflict" doesn't mean "crashes." It just means "you need to write some code to decide what to do." That said, and particularly on iOS where you don't have a ton of CPU cores, you generally are going to want to just serialize the work onto a single context using `perform`.

Comment: Guys, can you just use `.privateQueueConcurrencyType`